# <a> with routerLink and fragment does not set focus on the element

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using angular 9.0.6. I have troubles with page navigation fulfilling WCAG standards.

My app-component looks like this:

```
<nav class="pageNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="" fragment="main-nav">Navigation</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="" fragment="main-section">Main section</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="" fragment="cookie">Cookies</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <header class="navHeader">
    <div class="projectLogo"></div>
  </header>
  <nav tabindex="-1" id="main-nav">
    <h2 class="sr-only">Navigation</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="/main" href="">Main page</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/about" href=""><About</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/contact" href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="main-section">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="cookie">
  <app-cookie-dialog></app-cookie-dialog>
</div>
```

In the rooting module I have set anchorScrolling:

```
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routerOptions)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I expected that the links to the anchors:

```
    <li><a [routerLink]="" fragment="main-nav">Navigation</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="" fragment="main-section">Main section</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="" fragment="cookie">Cookies information</a></li>
```

will scroll to the element with the id AND focus them. Unfortunately only the scroll works.

I tried using  elements with href only:

```
    <li><a href="#main-nav">Navigation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#main-section">Main section</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cookie">Cookies information</a></li>
```

and it worked as long as I was on the main page. On other pages using these links redirected me to the main page. (they always lead to localhost:4200/#....)

I found a workaround that read the current url and added it to the href. Route is provided be .ts file.

```
 <a [href]="this.route + '#main-nav'">Navigation</a>
```

It feels that it is not the right way to do it, so I'm looking for more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that focusing is not supported by angular right now. There is a feature requst for focusing elements: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30067

```
 <a [href]="this.route + '#main-nav'">Navigation</a>
```

Seems to be the best way to achieve it right now.